# How to Get String from Array while using Axios

Tags: parsing, axios

Im using axios and I want to get the "word and definitions" from this api https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/WORD_THAT_I_WANT_TO_SEARCH
here is my current code:

```
let input = prompt("Enter !meaning of /YOUR WORD");
if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("!meaning of")) {
                searchOutput = input.split("/");
                axios.get('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/' + searchOutput[1])
                    .then(response => {
                    console.log("Meaning of " + searchOutput[1] + "\n\n\n" + response.data.join('\n'));
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The below piece of code gives you the definitions in a single line: change the deliminator I have used `--OR--`**

- You will get the result in a single line separated by `--OR--`

```js
let input = prompt("Enter !meaning of /YOUR WORD"); // take input

if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("!meaning of")) {
    const searchOutput = input.split("/");
    axios.get('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/' + searchOutput[1])
        .then(response => {
            let definitions = ""
            console.log('Meaning of the ' + response.data[0].word + ' is:')
            for (let i = 0; i < response.data[0].meanings.length; i++) {
                let res = response.data[0].meanings[i].definitions[0].definition
                definitions += res + " --OR-- ";
            }
            console.log(definitions)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Check the output of the response object (from axios output) in the console and grab the data you require from it.

**Output:**

- See the following images for checking the output
  [prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCw24.png)
  [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7TWe.png)

Let me know if your requirement is satisfied or not

Comment: what type of loop you used in this code?

Comment: I have used FOR loop

Comment: how can i join and join the definition? It's sending one by one, I want it to send all in one with all definitions

Comment: do you want all the definitions of a particular word in a line..??

Comment: yesss, exactly....

Comment: updated plese check!!